# Where do I suggest new Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, site-proposal

Is there an appropriate place to suggest new Stack Exchange based sites, perhaps a place for them to be voted upon?

I wish there was a Stack Exchange site for Aviation (both real-life and simulated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can submit a new site proposal at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

There currently is a proposal up for [General Aviation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7029/general-aviation). You can follow it and participate in the beta, if/when it gets enough traction.